# How to realize ajax .done in livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I want to refresh some html in other container, not where the button is.

In native ajax is like this

```
.done(function(result){
                     $('#result').html(result); 
                  });
```

how it works in livewire alpinejs?

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 option

1. use Livewire Life Cycle Javascript Hooks
   you can see the livewire javascript hooks in this link
   [Lifecycle Hooks](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks)

   ```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
   Livewire.hook('message.processed', (message, component) => {})
   ```

   });
2. Use Browser Events Dispatching

   [Dispatching Browser Events](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events)
   you can dispatch a browser event when ever you want in you backend like this

```
$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('name-updated', ['newName' => $value]);
```

and for js side you can use this code:

```js
window.addEventListener('name-updated', event => {
    alert('Name updated to: ' + event.detail.newName);
})
```